# Spot vs fwd bond

Tags: bond, bond-yields, bond-futures

Slight confusion here; say I am long a 10y bond and short the same bond 3m fwd.

Roughly over 3m I earn:

Carry on my spot pos = 3m9.75y yield - 10y yield.

Roll on my spot = 10y yield - 9.75 yield

Total on spot = 3m9.75y yield - 9.75yield

Roll on my fwd = -(3m9.75y yield - 9.75y yield)

Total is 0.

Theres clearly an issue with what I am doing. Could someone pls point out the flaw in my reasoning above. Thanks.